# If $ locks a column in Excel, what makes the row number progress one?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an issue when dragging a formula in Excel, where the number does not progress one place.

Example:

```
=AVERAGE('Wage 17-18'!$G3,'Wage 18-19'!$G3,'Wage 19-20'!$G3)
```

I want the number 3 to change to 4 and so on, but it does not.

Comment: I've tried copying the formula `=AVERAGE($G3, $G3, $G3)` into an Excel sheet and it seems to drag down just fine, changing to G4, G5 and so on. Maybe if it doesn't work with a reference to another sheet, you could always try importing the data onto one sheet.

Comment: If your question is about Excel for Windows / Mac then it's off-topic in [webapps.se] but it could be on-topic in [su] and/or [so].

Comment: Are you copying the cell itself or the formula from the formula bar? You do not want to do the latter

Answer (score 0):

When dragging the cell down, only the numbers should change since you locked the column (with the $).

I believe you may be dragging the to the left or right. If you are dragging to the left or right, the numbers won't change for your case.

`G3` can be dragged up/down and left/right and the numbers (and letters) will change

- if dragged up/down, the number will change to (`G2` or `G4`)
- if dragged left/right, the letter will change to (`F3` or `I3`)

`$G3`

- if dragged up/down, the number will change to (`G2` or `G4`)
- if dragged left/right, the **letter will not change because it's locked**
- if dragged right and down, the number will change, but the letter will stay the same

`G$3`

- if dragged up/down, the **number will not change because it's locked**
- if dragged left/right, the letter will change to (`F3` or `I3`)
- if dragged right and down, the number stay the same, but the letter will change

`$G$3`

- Nothing will change if dragged